# Why do I get a SQL syntax error with this?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, linqpad, isnull, iif

Trying to run this query in LINQPad 4:

```
SELECT item_group_id as AccountID, IIF(ISNULL(t_item_group.description),'[blank]',t_item_group.description) AS Name 
FROM t_item_group 
WHERE active = TRUE
```

I get, "*the isnull function requires 2 argument(s).*"

I've tried moving the parens around, changing the "[blank]" to "[blank]" and "[blank]" , but none of it helps...

The queries (I have two similar ones (with IIF(ISNULL)) that LINQPad won't run for this reason, yet they run in actuality (in my Web API app) fine; so, LINQPad is more "picky" than it needs to be, perhaps, but what is it expecting, SQL syntax-wise?

Comment: Please don't downvote without comment. If this is a duplicate, instead link to the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ISNULL` is already like a 'if' type statement.

You can just replace

```
IIF(ISNULL(t_item_group.description),'[blank]',t_item_group.description)
```

with

```
ISNULL(t_item_group.description, '[blank]')
```

The `ISNULL` uses the first parameter (the 'description'), unless that value is null in which case it will use the second parameter.

---

As an aside, one of the reasons I don't care for `ISNULL` is that it is poorly named. You'd assume that given its name it will return a bit - true if the parameter is null, false if not null - which you could use in an 'if' statement like you attempted. But that's not how it works.

The alternative is to use `COALESCE`. It provides much the same functionality, but the naming makes sense.

> co·a·lesce *ˌkōəˈles* verb
>   1. come together and form one mass or whole.

To `COALESCE` two parameters is to force them into one non-nullable result. And the function is actually more powerful, as you can provide multiple parameters - `COALESCE(i.description, i.name, '[blank]')` is perfectly valid.

Comment: Differences between `ISNULL` and `COALESCE`:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2008/06/26/differences-between-isnull-and-coalesce.aspx

Comment: Do you think the definition and phonetic pronunciation of COALESCE is helpful here, or even relevant? Personally, I find it kind of insulting.

Comment: @AaronBertrand yes, I think the definition of coalesce is helpful. It's not a commonly used term. By answer is based on the understanding that `COALESCE` is a well named function, so removing any ambiguity about the meaning of the term is helpful. I doubt you find my inclusion of the definition as insulting as I found your comment.

Comment: Ok, whatever... the insulting part is that if someone doesn't know what it means, or how to pronounce it, you're suggesting that they don't have the mental capacity to consult a dictionary on their own. You can disagree all you like; I'm just telling you how it looks to me. In case that's ambiguous: **in·sult·ing** *in-suhl-ting*: giving or causing insult; characterized by affronting rudeness, insolence, etc.

Comment: I don't have to define and phonetically pronounce every word in a code sample to provide an answer to a question, or for the reader to make use of the code. If they want to do further reading about why the SQL standard chose such a word, or how to pronounce it, or discover its Latin roots, they are more than welcome to do that. Doesn't make it any less insulting if I shove any of that down their throats in my answer.

Comment: I've edited your answer as the definition of the word is irrelevant to the answer.

Comment: See, that wasn't so hard, was it?

Comment: Why insult someone's intelligence when you don't have to? Why don't you do a search here and see how many users posting an answer about COALESCE felt it necessary to include the definition of the word, along with the phonetics in case they weren't just too dumb to look it up, they also couldn't figure out how to pronounce it, either.